# How to copy formula result

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

How do I copy a formula result?

I select which rows to keep in the worksheet "UI", by marking the rows with the value 1 in column B.

I assigned the following macro to a command button, which copies the selected rows to the worksheet "Output":

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UI")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
    
    For i = 2 To ws1.Range("B999").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws1.Cells(i, 2) = "1" Then ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

As the values in the rows are the results of formulas, the results pasted in "Output" come back as invalid cell references.

Is there a way of copy-pasting as text?

Comment: Just out of interest, do you have data in column A, and does it have a header? With a filter, you could copy all the rows in one action, rather than using a loop.

Comment: Just write to the `.Value` property of a cell to replace a formula with its result. Is in `Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value` or for multiple rows `Range("A2").Resize(10,1).Value = Range("A2").Resize(10,1).Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "xlPasteValues" property to avoid invalid cell references when values in the rows are the results of formulas. You can try to modify your code as follows:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheets("UI")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Output")
    
    For i = 2 To ws1.Range("B999").End(xlUp).Row
        If ws1.Cells(i, 2) = "1" Then
             ws1.Rows(i).Copy
             ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Sweet, this solved the issue! Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values of Rows with Criteria

- It's not quite *nifty*, but efficient.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "UI"
    Const sFirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Criteria As String = "1" ' 'Const Criteria as long = 1'?
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Output"
    Const dCell As String = "A2"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' Define Source Range (assuming 'UsedRange' starts in cell 'A1').
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = wb.Worksheets(sName).UsedRange
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = rg.Value ' assuming 'rg' has at least two cells
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Data, 2)
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    
    ' Loop and write matching values to the beginning of Data Array.
    For i = sFirstRow To UBound(Data, 1)
        cValue = Data(i, 2)
        If Not IsError(cValue) Then
            If cValue = Criteria Then
                k = k + 1
                For j = 1 To cCount
                    Data(k, j) = Data(i, j)
                Next j
            End If
        End If
    Next i
     
    ' Write matching values from Data Array to Destination Range.
    If k > 0 Then
        With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dCell)
            .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
                .Worksheet.Columns.Count - .Column + 1).ClearContents
            .Resize(k, cCount).Value = Data
        End With
        MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "No matches found.", vbExclamation, "Fail?"
    End If

End Sub
```